# Unable to destructure property 'TouchBarButton' of 'TouchBar' in custom BetterDiscord extension code

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I am new to JS and am trying to make a BetterDiscord extension, however my code is throwing the error:

```
Cannot destructure property 'TouchBarButton' of 'TouchBar' as it is undefined
```

The code:

```js
//META{"name":"BetterTouchbar"}*//
const { app, BrowserWindow, TouchBar } = require('electron');
const { TouchBarButton } = TouchBar;
class BetterTouchbar {

    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        this.initialized = false;
    }

    // Meta
    getName() { return "BetterTouchbar"; }
    getShortName() { return "BT"; }
    getDescription() { return "Eek"; }
    getVersion() { return "0.1.0"; }
    getAuthor() { return "Aj3douglas#7472"; }

    start(){
        console.log("Better touchbar has been started!");
        BdApi.showToast("Better touchbar has been launched!")
        // const touchBar = new TouchBar({
        //     items: [],
        // })
        // window.setTouchBar(touchBar)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting `const { TouchBarButton } = TouchBar;` from? You need to put `TouchBarButton` inside the curly braces of the first require statement.

Comment: Are you sure you have `electron` installed, i.e you have electron in your package.json and have run `npm install`? As the code seems correct - https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/touch-bar#examples

Comment: It would be useful, for the next time, if you could specify the type error you get and where in your code you get it. See comment above for a possible solution.

Comment: Hello, I sorted out that issue, however upon making a new TouchBarButton instance I receive a `TouchBarButton` is not a constructor issue

Comment: best to put up how you solved your issue for others in future and create a new question with your new issue